# Issue targeting specific selector jquery in dropdwon menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, jquery-selectors, this

I have a drop down menu with jquery and I want to modify some text in different way depending on what is selected in the drop down menu.

The drop down menu works.

Html code:

```
<div>
<ul class="myMenu">
    <li><a href="#">Choose your location</a>
        <ul>
            <li id="op1"><a href="#Co">option1</a></li>
            <li id="op2"><a href="#Nk">option2</a></li>
            <li id="op2"><a href="#So">option3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
<div>
<h1 id="text_to_change">Welcome to blabla</h1>
</div>
```

Javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.myMenu li ul li').click( function(event){
    $(document).find('#text_to_change').css('visibility', 'visible');
    $('.myMenu').hide();
    if ($(this) == '#op1'){
        $('#text_to_change').text("text changed");
    }
    if ($(this) == '#op2'){
        $('#text_to_change').text("text changed differently");
    }
    else{
        $('#text_to_change').text("text changed differently again");
    }
});
});
```

Why does `($(this) == '#op1')` not work?

Comment: `==` is arithmatic comparison.  I think you need `===` to compare two strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to compare a jquery object `$(this)` with a string `#op1`

To get the id of the element use:

```
$(this).attr('id');
```

It will give you the id of the element without the `#`

Also i think your second if needs to be an `else if { ...`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.myMenu li ul li').click( function(event){
    
    console.log($(this).attr('id'), $(this).prop('id'));
    $(document).find('#text_to_change').css('visibility', 'visible');
    $('.myMenu').hide();
    if ($(this).attr('id') == 'op1'){
        $('#text_to_change').text("text changed");
    }
    else if ($(this).attr('id') == 'op2'){
        $('#text_to_change').text("text changed differently");
    }
    else{
        $('#text_to_change').text("text changed differently again");
    }
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<ul class="myMenu">
    <li><a href="#">Choose your location</a>
        <ul>
            <li id="op1"><a href="#Co">option1</a></li>
            <li id="op2"><a href="#Nk">option2</a></li>
            <li id="op2"><a href="#So">option3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
<div>
<h1 id="text_to_change">Welcome to blabla</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... I got stuck for too long on that.

Answer (score 0):

This two item must not share the same id 'op2'

```
<li id="op2"><a href="#Nk">option2</a></li>
<li id="op2"><a href="#So">option3</a></li>
```